# Are there exact solutions for the following system of nonlinear first order ordinary differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

The two equations are:

```
u'[t]== -(K + L v[t])  u[t]
```

and

```
 v'[t] == -L u[t]  v[t]
```

where K and L are constants. At t=0, u(0)=a positive initial value and v(0)=a different initial value which is much lower than u(0).  As t approaches infinity, u approaches 0 and v approaches the initial value for v(0).

My two questions are whether there is an exact solution for this system, and, if so, what are they?

Comment: **u(t)=-Ku(t)-Lu(t)v(t) and v(t)=R-Lu(t)v(t)** how are these differential equations? I see no derivatives anywhere?

Comment: Welcome, please provide your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have a feeling you meant to write  `u'[t]==-K*u[t]-L*u[t]*v[t],v'[t]==L*u[t]*v[t]`  Do you have numerical values for these constants? Also for the IC?. Please do not describe the problem using just words. But give an actual concrete example.

Comment: Yes, Nasser, you are correct, the left side of both equations should have been derivatives.  I have since edited that and deleted the constant R that was originally in the second equation.  Constant values will depend on experimental conditions, but typical values are  K=0.164, L=1.49x10-8, u(o)=1.05 and v(0)=1x10-6.  I have tried no code.

Comment: I don't know if my edit of the preceding comment was allowed, so I note that L=1.49x10+8 is the correct value.

Comment: I changed your L., still no solution using DSolve but only with NDSolve. I know you are asking for analytical solution, but DSolve simply can't solve it analytically. May be try again in version 14.

Comment: Nasser,  thanks for trying.  I have been struggling with this for weeks, so I know it's not easy.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that obtaining a symbolic solution for this ODE system problem is not possible.  However, obtaining a first-integral is straightforward and may be useful, depending on the author's goals.  Because the ODEs are autonomous, (i.e., `t` does not enter explicitly), an ODE for u[v] can be derived as follows.

```
eq1 = u'[t] == -k u[t] - m u[t] v[t]
eq2 = v'[t] == -m u[t] v[t]
```

Dividing `eq1` by `eq2` then yields

```
equ = Simplify[u'[v] == (-k u[v] - m u[v] v)/(-m u[v] v)]
(* 1 + k/(m v) == u'[v] *)
```

which is readily solved.

```
DSolve[equ, u[v], v][[1, 1]]
(* u[v] -> v + C[1] + (k Log[v])/m *)
```

Returning to `t` dependence then provides the first-integral.

```
Equal @@ % /. {u[v] -> u[t], v -> v[t]}
(* u[t] == C[1] + (k Log[v[t]])/m + v[t] *)
```

Note that, in order for `u[t]` to be zero for `t` approaching infinity but not for `t = 0`, but `v[t]` to have the same value (say, `v[0]`) in both cases, `v[t]` must pass through a branch cut, further complicating the problem. Finally, `v[t]` can be obtained, although the result probably is not very helpful.

```
eq2 /. u -> Function[{t}, C[1] + (k Log[v[t]])/m + v[t]];
sv = DSolve[%, v[t], t][[1, 1]]
(* v[t] -> InverseFunction[Inactive[Integrate][1/
 (K[1] (m C[1] + m K[1] + k Log[K[1]])), {K[1], 1, #1}] &][-t + C[2]] *)
```

or, equivalently,

```
sv[[2, 1]] == Head[sv[[2]]][[1]][sv[[1]]] /. K[1] -> z /. C[2] -> 0 /. 
    Inactive[Integrate][a_, {z, 1, v[t]}] -> Inactive[Integrate][a, {z, v[0], v[t]}]
(* -t == Inactive[Integrate][1/
   (z (m z + m C[1] + k Log[z])), {z, v[0], v[t]}] *)
```

This integral is similar to that obtained by Nasser and probably cannot be solved symbolically and then inverted, especially considering that it too almost certainly involves a branch cut.

**Addendum**

For completeness, I should add that the system of ODEs has an obvious but perhaps trivial symbolic solution.  Suppose that `v[t]` is identically `0`.  Then,

```
{eq1, eq2} /. v -> Function[{t}, 0]
(* {u'[t] == -k u[t], True} *)

DSolve[%[[1]], u[t], t][[1, 1]]
{* u[t] -> E^(-k t) C[1] *}
```

which indeed satisfies both the ODEs and their boundary conditions.

Answer (score 2):

DSolve can't solve it. Not surprising, as non linear system of ode's are very hard to solve analytically. The non-linearity here comes because you have the product of dependent variables in the odes.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
k = SetAccuracy[0.164, Infinity]
L = SetAccuracy[1.49*10^(8), Infinity]
ode1 = u'[t] == -k*u[t] - L*u[t]*v[t]
ode2 = v'[t] == -L*u[t]*v[t]
ic = {u[0] == Rationalize[1.05], v[0] == Rationalize[1*10^(-6)]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now

```
sol = DSolve[{ode1, ode2, ic}, {u[t], v[t]}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image]

So your best chance is numerical solution

```
sol = NDSolve[{ode1, ode2, ic}, {u, v}, {t, 0, 100}];
Plot[{Evaluate[u[t] /. sol], Evaluate[v[t] /. sol]}, {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"u(t)", "v(t)"}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

fyi, tried it in Maple. It also can't solve it but it does give partial result. The reason it can't solve it is that the integrals are hard to solve as shown

```
k := convert(0.164,rational);
L := convert(1.49*10^(8), rational);
ode1 := diff(u(t),t)= -k*u(t) - L*u(t)*v(t);
ode2 := diff(v(t),t) = -L*u(t)*v(t);
ic := u(0) = convert(1.05,rational), v(0) = convert(1*10^(-6),rational);
```

[image]

And now

```
dsolve([ode1,ode2,ic])
```

[image]

In plain text:

```
{u(t) = RootOf(250*Int(1/(37250000000*_f+41*ln(_f)+39112462750+246*ln(10))/_f,
_f = 1/1000000 .. _Z)+t)+41/37250000000*ln(RootOf(250*Int(1/(37250000000*_f+41*
ln(_f)+39112462750+246*ln(10))/_f,_f = 1/1000000 .. _Z)+t))+1049999/1000000+123
/18625000000*ln(10), v(t) = RootOf(250*Int(1/(37250000000*_f+41*ln(_f)+
39112462750+246*ln(10))/_f,_f = 1/1000000 .. _Z)+t)}
```

If you can integrate these, then you might get your analytical solution.

Answer (score 1):

Its clear, that the equations have constant solutions

0 == -(K + L v[t])  u[t]

and

0 == -L u[t]  v[t]

Since both equations have the form

```
 Log[u]'== -(K + L v[t])
```

and

```
 Log[v]'== -L u[t]
```

so eg.

```
   v[t] = Exp[-Integrate[- L u[s],{s,0,t}]
```

Its clear that both equations tend to the constant solutions exponentially, because the Logs fall constantly for any positive u,v.

Mathematica solves the system symbolically using inverse functions of the integral of the exponentials. Expressions are too large  to transfer them here and useless, probably in practice.